# Padding-top not working

Tags: html, css, padding

Why doesn't `padding-top` work? The height of the `div` is set.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">APIE MUS</a>
    <a href="#">REKLAMA</a>
    <a href="#">PARTNERIAI</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .menu {
      width: 300px;
      height: 30px;
      background: red;
 }
 .menu a {
      padding-top: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: And what is it you're actually trying to do? (I *think* you want `.menu {line-height: 30px;}`) also you seem to be using `padding-top` and `margin-top` interchangeably. Which one is it that you're really using?

Comment: tryin add 10px space from top, that links will below 10px

Comment: So: `.menu {padding-top: 10px;}`?

Comment: no, in menu can be also text, 10px is only for links

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Your example (with margin) does not work because you can't apply margin to inline elements like `a, span, b`.

#### Take a look:

- http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/
- http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm

#### To fix your issue:

Just add `display:inline-block;`

> This value (inline-block) causes an element to generate an inline-level block
>   container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box,
>   and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.
>   **Source:** http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-level

So this will fix your issue:

```
.menu a{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```